# My sidebar widgets are not vertical in Wordpress? How Do I Align It Correctly?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, widget

I have a theme that I'm making, and the sidebar never works properly. The Widgets or asides don't align vertically and goes horizontal. I've done everything in css even changing sidebar.php and nothing has worked.

For Reference: http://minecraftserverzz.com/youtube/hai/

[image]

This is what i've added to sidebar.php and i've cleared all css to see what the main problem could be.

```
<div id="sidebar" class="widgets-area">
 <?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>
    <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-primary' ) ) : ?>
        <aside id="search" class="widget widget_search">
           <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </aside>
        <aside id="archives" class"widget">
            <h1 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Archives', 'shape' ); ?></h1>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly' ) ); ?>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <aside id="meta" class="widget">
            <h1 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Meta', 'shape' ); ?></h1>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_register(); ?>
                <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
                <?php wp_meta(); ?>
            </ul>
        </aside>
   <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: edit your question and paste all of your relevant code there, hit CTRL+ M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#sidebar` has `display: flex;` and by default, flex's `flex-direction` is `row`. Meaning it will lay things out horizontally, not vertically. To make that layout vertical, apply `flex-direction: column;` to `#sidebar`

Comment: Thank you so much, i was getting really frustrated and that really helped.

Comment: @McDiamund np! Though fwiw, you can also just remove `display: flex;` entirely from `#sidebar` unless you have a specific reason to use flexbox there. The default behavior of block elements is to stack one on top of another, so the `aside`s in `#sidebar` will be one on top of one another without flexbox. Though I just checked your website and you used `display: column;` (that's invalid) and `position: absolute;`?

Comment: oops, my bad. I just changed it :) Also, i have a question as well. how do you make it where a sidebar takes up a specific length of the page no matter how much content is pushing the footer down? It may be a lot but i was just wondering

Comment: @McDiamund you can't with the way your markup is now. What I would do is wrap #content and #sidebar in a new div, and use flexbox. Here's an example based on the 60%/30% layout of your site currently http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBZKXe

Comment: Thank you for that good piece on info, i hope you have a fantastic day wherever you are :)